# How to create this array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, sorting

I need to create an array called BigArray. BigArray needs to contain words from below arrays.

There are three arrays called "users". Each such array has certain words in it like:

Users1: Cat, Dog, Bat

Users2: Apple, Mango, Banana, Pear

Users3: Big, Small

I want to arrange above words in BigArray in following way:
Cat, Apple, Big, Dog, Mango, Small, Bat, Banana, Pear

How can I do that?

Comment: What is the logic behind the filling of BigArray? When to use which element from which array?

Comment: I need to create BigArray by picking elements turn by turn from each Users array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution will work even if your Userx arrays do not all have the **same size**:

```
NSMutableArray BigArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray u1 = [Users1 mutableCopy];
NSMutableArray u2 = [Users2 mutableCopy];
NSMutableArray u3 = [Users3 mutableCopy];
while ([u1 count] || [u2 count] || [u3 count]) {
    if ([u1 count]) {
        [BigArray addObject:[u1 objectAtIndex:0]];
        [u1 removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    }
    if ([u2 count]) {
        [BigArray addObject:[u2 objectAtIndex:0]];
        [u2 removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    }
    if ([u3 count]) {
        [BigArray addObject:[u3 objectAtIndex:0]];
        [u3 removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    }
}
[u1 release];
[u2 release];
[u3 release];
/* BigArray now contains what you need */
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a NSMutable array FinalArray
2. Run through each of your smaller arrays
3. Add each object from each of the smaller arrays at index 0 to n to the FinalArray in the same forloop.

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps

```
NSArray *a1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Cat", @"Dog", @"Bat",nil];
NSArray *a2 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Apple", @"Mango", @"Banana", @"Pear",nil];
NSArray *a3 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Big", @"Small",nil];
NSUInteger arrayLength = [a1 count]+[a2 count]+[a3 count]; 
NSMutableArray *finalMutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:(arrayLength)];
for (NSUInteger index = 0; index < [a2 count]; index++) { // take the size of the biggest array
if(index < [a1 count])
    [finalMutableArray addObject:[a1 objectAtIndex:index]];
[finalMutableArray addObject:[a2 objectAtIndex:index]];
if(index < [a3 count])
    [finalMutableArray addObject:[a3 objectAtIndex:index]];
}
NSArray *finalArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:finalMutableArray];
[a1 release];
[a2 release];
[a3 release];
```

Comment: Why did you take arrayLength * numberOfArrays? You are creating an array with only arrayLength elements.

Comment: Looks better now. Your previous code also worked fine, I just thought it looked a bit off.

Comment: @Vaiko: Didnt optimize the code well enough before. Was in a hurry to post the answer.